# Multigroup field in view only showing single delta

Tags: views, 6, entities

How are CCK multi groups handled in a view? Because when I select the fields for the views, they come with a "delta" field:

[image]

The delta fields are always empty, so it doesn't work out of the box. The delta fields are always empty in the table view.

Is there any way I can have support for multigroup fields, or even a way to concatenate the delta's of the three fields ('Naam', 'Bedrijfsnaam', 'E-mailadres') for each delta?

Comment: What version of Views are you using?  I don't see this behavior with Views 3 and CCK 3 w/multigroups

Comment: @Jimajamma I'm using Views 2.16. I will try updating it and reporting back.

Comment: @Jimajamma I can't upgrade to Views 3, as the download page basically says "there is an upgrade bug from 2.x to 3".

Comment: well that's a :(  let me see if I can find a system with drupal 6, cck 3 and views 2 around here to play with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to get this to work on Drupal 6, CCK 3 and Views 2, I spun up a testbed on the ever trusty [Pantheon](http://www.getpantheon.com) and created a content type:

[image]

and then created three nodes, the first one had two sets of name/biz/email, the second had one and the third had three.

I then created a View:

[image]

with these results which I hope is what you were after.

[image]

Things that needed to be done differently:

One.  Add in that Content multigroup filter.  I just chose 'Name' as the field to join on.

Two.  Turn off all grouping of the Fields, eg uncheck this in their setup:

[image]

Three.  Put all the values in the Global Custom Text field:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for, and wrapped in a beautiful example. +1!